# Difference between [[x], [y], [z]] and [x, y, z]

Tags: python, list

There are two types of list in Python, `[[x], [y], [z]]` and `[x, y, z]`. At least in the variable explorer both are stated as "list".

What is the difference? Can I work with them together? How can I transfer one into the other to actually work with them together?

Comment: ...what? Yes, they're both lists. One of them is a list that contains lists, the other isn't. Or maybe it is, depending on what `x`, `y` and `z` are. There *aren't* *"two types of list in Python"*, and it's not at all clear what gave you the idea that there were.

Comment: There is no "two types of list". There is "list" which is an object which can contains anything. So, a list can contain numbers, or others lists, which itself can contain other lists.

Comment: ah, I see. Listception.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. I will work with that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`[[x],[y],[z]]` is *list of lists* whereas `[x, y, z]` is just a *list*.

In order to convert them, you may use *list comprehensions* as:

```
# convert list -> list of lists
>>> my_list = [1, 2, 3]
>>> [[i] for i in my_list]
[[1], [2], [3]]

# convert list of lists -> list
>>> my_list_of_lists = [[1], [2], [3]]
>>> [j for i in my_list_of_lists for j in i]
[1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Thank you all for the quick and precise answers. A newcomer appreciates them.

Comment: @FloridaMan If this answer helped you, please follow this guide for the next steps: http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: I had to wait 8min to accept ;-) Thanks for the help.